# How can I hide the status bar in VS Code?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

How can I hide the status bar in Visual Studio Code?

It should be possible to hide the status bar. Is there any way to hide it?
In the "View" menu, I cannot find an option to hide it.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
View > Appearance > Show Status Bar
```

Screenshot from version 1.42.0
[image]

<s>At version 1.4, go to View-> Toggle status bar</s>

Comment: For those who want the same for the menu, use: View -> Toggle menu bar

Comment: In v1.12 the options is shown as `View -> Hide Status Bar` when status bar is visible and `View -> Show Status Bar` when status bar is hidden.

Comment: How do I customize the color? Royal blue is too dim for me. I'd like to set mine to a flashing neon green and pink.

Comment: @kmiklas Go to File> Preferences> Settings
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "statusBar.background": "#39fe15",
    "statusBar.foreground": "#ff9db8"
  }

Comment: I am using version 1.4 but did not find View-> Toggle status bar. View menu has only 'Toggle Word Wrap' option in toggle options.

Comment: Got it, the answer is View > Appearance > Show/Hide Status Bar

Comment: @Kamlesh Are you using version 1.4(1.04)? Right now is 1.41.1, it's a different version.

Answer (score 8):

`View > Appearance > Show/Hide Status Bar`

Answer (score 5):

I think you should have a  try at this... 
Go to Tools(at the Menu Bar)->Options(at the bottom)->General->Show Status Bar(Uncheck it ) and then press OK.

Answer (score 4):

Find your key bindings preferences by entering ctrl + P.  That will take you to your control panel and vscode even makes it easier to change the keys by only needing to press the keys.  search for statusbar and just set it to something else like I did here.  I toggle when I want to see it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right now the team have not open the permission for customising status bar (I mean show/hide, or change it to another colour).

But there has been a feature request about that. Others could trace this issue there:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1884

Comment: we can customize the color by edit the style sheet in workbench.main.css.

Answer (score 2):

Guy above nearly had it -

Tools(at the Menu Bar)->Options(at the bottom)->General->Environment > Status Bar

100% works

Answer (score 2):

Open the `settings.json` and add:

```
{
    // hide menu-bar, can be displayed pressing the Alt key
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
    // Alt key no longer displays the menu-bar (useful when using i3 on Linux)
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
press : ctrl+shift+P -> Open settings (JSON) -> "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode 1.36
Go to Menu View -> Appearances -> Show Status Bar

This will enable back on check and hide on uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, 17 Feb 2020, with the latest version of VSC.
Just press the settings icon at the bottom left of your screen. A new tab opens in the editor. Go to workbench then appearance and find the status bar and check the visibility box.

Answer (score 0):

Easily. to hide, left-click on status bar.
to show, (v1.4 .. 1.58) go on view. then appearance.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to hide certain items from the `status bar` instead of disabling it completely:

Right click on `status bar` and untick items:

[image]

Answer (score -5):

Go to Options->Environment->General->Uncheck show status bar->Ok

Comment: This is not a valid answer.