# I deleted the bottom bar VScode which shows the errors, how can I restore it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The bottom bar of VScode which shows the errors is gone, how can I restore it

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "deleted the bottom bar"? Try using the shortcut "Ctrl + ` (backtick)" to bring up a window and then press the "Problems" tab. Is that what you mean?

Comment: goto menu: **View** > **Appearance** and select what you want to see

Comment: You are referring to the `Status Bar`, by the way.

Comment: Mark: Yes sir...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide the status bar in vs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117555/how-can-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-vs-code) (The answers describe how to hide it, but just do the reverse to show/display it again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `View > Appearance > Show Status Bar`

[image]